# How can I best store and send SNMP messages to ios?

Tags: iphone, linux, architecture, activemq-classic, snmp

My goal is to transfer SNMP messages from a client's (possibly firewalled) back-end servers, store them in some fast database server, and push them to an iOS device (http://bit.ly/vwBf5).

What are my choices?

1. Encapsulate a snmp message and transfer it over http to db server, then push to iOS and store in some db. SNMP Agent -> Processing server (some engine to process incoming messages) -> push to iOS
2. Use some snmp agent to catch then. Use own ActiveMQ server to push to IOS an use some fast persistence db. Agent -> ActiveMQ server (Hadoop for persistance) -> iOS

In db I will store login, time, message, origin, sent to apple, server id, and username. Most of the time the database will only write, though sometimes it will read (from web requests).

What are my options: Hadoop, Cassandra, Mongo?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, kinda blurry scenario. However, since you already consider ActiveMQ, please take a look at Apache Camel also, it kindof does what you want (probably, since it's a bit hard to follow):

[Camel has support](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) to read of SNMP traps (or poll for SNMP messages), as well as support to send messages to APNS as well as multiple databases (including MongoDB, Hadoop as well as JDBC compliant SQL servers).

Just an example of how it could look like in Camel code (note that you need some custom formatting of the messages as well as configuration for it to work, of course, so please don't try to run this code as is):

```
from("snmp:127.0.0.1:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")  // from SNMP trap
   .convertBodyTo(String.class)
   .setHeader(ApnsConstants.HEADER_TOKENS, constant(IOS_DEVICE_TOKEN))
   .to("apns:notify") // TO iOS
   .to("mongodb:myDb?database=mySnmp&collection=traps&operation=insert"); // To DB
```

Or if you feel you have to do some staging because of high peak loads of traps, you could do that as well:

```
from("snmp:127.0.0.1:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")  // from SNMP trap
   .convertBodyTo(String.class)
   .to("seda:stagedProcess");  // 

from("sead:stagedProcess")
   .setHeader(ApnsConstants.HEADER_TOKENS, constant(IOS_DEVICE_TOKEN))
   .to("apns:notify") // TO iOS
   .to("mongodb:myDb?database=mySnmp&collection=traps&operation=insert"); // To DB
```

Comment: We're having snmp trap server at client's premises.  But middleware service is needed for authentication, authorization and transport. Here's how's our architecture will look. [Architecture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31008398/infrastructure.png)